# ubuntu scipy works for python2.7 but not for 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I have tried many ways to get scipy to play nice with python3.2 but no joy yet.

I have tried:

```
  sudo apt-get build-dep scipy
```

no joy

and

```
    sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

and still no joy

The goal is to get scipy to play nice with ipython running python3.2.

Here is the terminal output.
http://pastebin.com/LkPZUSAX

help / assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
sudo apt-get install python32-numpy
```

if you have multiple versions of python installed on your system then you have to specify the version for which you want to install the library..

also you can do

```
python --version
```

to check the default python for your system

Comment: Tried above:sudo apt-get install python32-numpy   message:  Unable to locate package python32-numpy  Currently running: $ python3.2
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 20:10:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.7.0'  It's scipy I'm trying to get to work. >>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy I welcome further suggested fixes.

Comment: my bad... 
`sudo apt-get install python3-numpy python3-scipy`

http://www.andrewsturges.com/2012/05/installing-numpy-16-for-python-3-in.html

Comment: You can use packages.ubuntu.com to check package names [like this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=numpy&searchon=names&suite=raring&section=all).

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command

```
sudo apt-get install python3.2-numpy
```

instead.

Running the command

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

installs for python2.7 be default in my case.

So one must specify the python version in apt-get command.